# HDFS is for Big Data storage and Azure storage

Tags: hdfs, azure-blob-storage

I am using HDFS to store the data files. Want to know is there a way to use Azure storage to be used in the place of HDFS? If so how.
I am using Spark and Python.

Comment: Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 is Azure Blob Storage with a hierarchical namespace attached, and is fully HDFS compatible. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-introduction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post an answer to end this question. As @Joel Cochran comments, you can use Azure Data Lake Gen2 which is fully HDFS compatible. You can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-introduction to start it.